# MAGENTO 1.7 - List.phtml displaying an unwanted "No" next to product name

Tags: php, magento

This is what it looks like:
[image: "no"]

And this is my code:

```
           <div class="product-name">
               <h22><?php echo (($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) && $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != "Nein") ? $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) : ''); ?>
               <?php echo (($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('weingut')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) && $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('weingut')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != "Nein") ? $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('weingut')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) : ''); ?>
               <?php echo (($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ob_hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) && $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ob_hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != "Nein") ? $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ob_hersteller')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) : ''); ?></h22></div>
```

Strangely the "no" only appears in the english version. We modified the list.phtml to show the company or manufacturer or vineyard.

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own SE site: magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW, `<h22>` is no valid HTML tag. And it makes me scared of your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if you value is equal to 'Nein' if different to 'Nein' you show it.

In the english version it's not 'Nein' it's no so it always show.

You should change it in your files or use the translation feature of Magento.

Comment: dagfr: If I change it to "No" it shows "Nein" on the german site (which is the main site). How do I get it to disappear in both EN and DE??

Comment: look at @fab comment : compare with $this->__('No') instead of 'Nein' if you have the translation of 'No' to 'Nein' in the german store it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if some attribute is "Nein" and display it if not. This attribute seems to be translated to "No" in English.

Comment: There's an explanation for the H22, don't worry.. ;)
How do I get it to NOT display the "no"????

Comment: compare with `$this->__('No')` instead of `'Nein'`